# XLS file created using XML format shown XML data in OpenOffice.org Calc and share on Google Drive

Tags: php, xml, xlsx

I have created XLS file using XML format in php. It show perfectly in Windows excel but when I open this with OpenOffice.org Calc or share on Google Drive then it show XML data. Can somebody help me for this issue.
File created using:

```
$html = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
                <?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
                <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                   xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
                   xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
                   xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
                   xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
                <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
                   <Author>TEST</Author>
                   <LastAuthor>TEST</LastAuthor>
                   <Created>TEST</Created>
                   <Version>1.00</Version>
                </DocumentProperties>
                <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
                   <WindowHeight>8250</WindowHeight>
                   <WindowWidth>21075</WindowWidth>
                   <WindowTopX>0</WindowTopX>
                   <WindowTopY>0</WindowTopY>
                   <ActiveSheet>0</ActiveSheet>
                   <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
                   <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
                </ExcelWorkbook>
                ' . $styleStr . '
                ' . $data . '
               </Workbook>';

    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
    echo $html;
    exit;
```

Where $styleStr is style string and $data is table data which is in XML format

Comment: Not really, unless you show how you're creating the file.... but a real xls file isn't an xml format.... perhaps you're thinking of an xlsx file, which is a zipped collection of xml files, or of SPreadsheetML

Comment: How can I create zipped collection of xml file.

Comment: Way to big a question for StackOverflow, if you want somebody to help you with writing code to create a real Excel file.... either use a library like PHPExcel to create your file, or narrow down your question a bit, because you obviously don't understand the various Excel format

Comment: So looks like you're using [SpreasheetML](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/SpreadsheetML)